# Load banner in Joomla article

Tags: plugin, articles, com-banners

Is there any plugin that can load banner "id x" from banner component? Or is there any other way, but not with {loadmoduleid x}?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/modulesanywhere

Comment: Yes but is it any way to load from component not from module. I tried Component anywhere but it is not possible.
With the Banners Component can't be created menu item, so in frontend links like: /index.php?option=com_banners&view=banner&id=11 do not work.
Or am I wrong?